# Is it possible to enumerate Rundeck input variables in script?

Tags: rundeck

Example usecase: Enumerate input options from Rundeck inputs by as script as an array to cycle through.
                 Dynamically read all user provided input options from Rundeck

I understand that inputs can be referenced by @option.inputname@
My question: Is there a input array that can be referenced in order to cycle through inputs?

Example language: Powershell

```
$Inputs = @options@

foreach($Input in $Inputs)
{
   Write-Host $Input
}
```

The question is not to cycle through an array for one input but instead collect all inputs as an array.

Job Eg:

- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  group: Test/Example
  id: e6c16942-baf0-4255-9c05-87bc11f66f6f
  loglevel: INFO
  name: StackOverflow-Example
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:

  - name: User
  - name: city
  - name: location
  - name: telephone
    scheduleEnabled: true
    sequence:
    commands:
  - script: getopts
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
    uuid: e6c16942-baf0-4255-9c05-87bc11f66f6f

Can options as an array be collected by commandline ? I know this is possible via Rundecks API but my use case will be to achieve this in-script :-)

Do not believe that this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in this way (my example is under Bash):

```
echo "starting"
for i in @option.opt1@
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

I leave the job definition with an editable option by any user:

```xml
    <joblist>
      <job>
        <context>
          <options preserveOrder='true'>
            <option name='opt1' value='1 2 3 4 5' />
          </options>
        </context>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description></description>
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>298a3027-ede0-47f0-be88-308647839b82</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobEnumerate</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
          <command>
            <script><![CDATA[echo "starting"

    for i in @option.opt1@
    do
       echo "Welcome $i times"
    done]]></script>
            <scriptargs />
          </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>298a3027-ede0-47f0-be88-308647839b82</uuid>
      </job>
    </joblist>
```

And the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1DR1.jpg).

Comment: thanks MegaDrive68k, I was more leaning toward iterating through rundeck input option(s) not iterating through the input in a single option, that an easy one :-)

My question was more aligned to collecting the list of options above as an array, and cycle through that.

ill update the question to reflect that